# ObservableCollection not updating though I INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I need to display in a DataGrid a set of bit states as received from external source. For this I use an ObservableCollection like this

```
public class UpdateIO : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

```
public static ObservableCollection<IObitDetails> PlcCommonOutputs = new ObservableCollection<IObitDetails>();
```

My IObitDetails class is

```
    public class IObitDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool _bitValue;
        public string BitGroup { get; set; }
        public string BitText { get; set; }
        public short CIOaddress { get; set; }
        public short BitPosition { get; set; }
        public bool BitValue
        {
            get { return _bitValue; }
            set { SetField(ref _bitValue, value); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        public IObitDetails(string bg, bool bv, string bt, short adr, short pos)
        {
            BitGroup = bg;
            BitValue = bv;
            BitText = bt;
            CIOaddress = adr;
            BitPosition = pos;
        }
    }
```

Next I created the collection

```
PlcCommonOutputs.Add(new IObitDetails("CO", oCommonOpLampRed,"Op. Red", 0x0001, obitCommonOpLampRed));
PlcCommonOutputs.Add(new IObitDetails("CO", oCommonOpLampGreen,"Op. Green", 0x0001, obitCommonOpLampGreen));
PlcCommonOutputs.Add(new IObitDetails("CO", oCommonMuteA,"MuteA", 0x0001, obitCommonMuteA));
PlcCommonOutputs.Add(new IObitDetails("CO", oCommonMuteB,"MuteB", 0x0001, obitCommonMuteB));
...
```

Here BitPositions are declared as:

```
private const short obitCommonOpLampRed = 0;
private const short obitCommonOpLampGreen = 1;
private const short obitCommonMuteA = 2;
private const short obitCommonMuteB = 3;
...
```

Each bit is a property which is modified when I read (in a polling thread) a port and store in oCommonOutputsPost:

```
        private short _oCommonOutputsPort;
        public short oCommonOutputsPort
        {
            get { return _oCommonOutputsPort; }
            set
            {
                SetField(ref _oCommonOutputsPort, value);
                oCommonOpLampRed = (oCommonOutputsPort & (1 << obitCommonOpLampRed)) != 0;
                oCommonOpLampGreen = (oCommonOutputsPort & (1 << obitCommonOpLampGreen)) != 0;
                oCommonMuteA = (oCommonOutputsPort & (1 << obitCommonMuteA)) != 0;
                oCommonMuteB = (oCommonOutputsPort & (1 << obitCommonMuteB)) != 0;
            }
        }

        private bool _oCommonOpLampRed;
        public bool oCommonOpLampRed
        {
            get { return _oCommonOpLampRed; }
            set { SetField(ref _oCommonOpLampRed, value); }
        }
        private bool _oCommonOpLampGreen;
        public bool oCommonOpLampGreen
        {
            get { return _oCommonOpLampGreen; }
            set { SetField(ref _oCommonOpLampGreen, value); }
            }
        }
        private bool _oCommonMuteA;
        public bool oCommonMuteA
        {
            get { return _oCommonMuteA; }
            set { SetField(ref _oCommonMuteA, value); }
        }
        private bool _oCommonMuteB;
        public bool oCommonMuteB
        {
            get { return _oCommonMuteB; }
            set { SetField(ref _oCommonMuteB, value); }
        }
...
```

Whenever I read a new port value, the bits are set/reset (I see that the bit properties are modified correctly).
But the ObservableCollection (PlcCommonOutputs) is not changed.
If I change by hand in debugger the corresponding BitValue(s) in the collection they are seen in the UI (so I do not include any xaml).
Is there a way this is done without increasing code complexity to much?

Comment: ObservableCollection only fires events when the collection is changed (e.g. elements added, removed, moved etc), not when individual elements change.

Comment: You may want to look at BindingList instead of ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this, would be to raise propertychanged when in your setter for the values you would want to update. An example of this would be:

```
private bool _oCommonMuteA;
public bool oCommonMuteA
{
    get { return _oCommonMuteA; }
    set 
    { 
        SetField(ref _oCommonMuteA, value); 
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(oCommonMuteA));
    }
 }
```

Comment: But I already have OnPropertyChanged in my SetField method before it.